# Finding coefficients of a third degree polynomial

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

The third degree polynomial $$-x^3 + ax^2+bx+c$$ has an maximum at $(2,10)$ and an inflation point at $(0,-6)$. Find the coefficients $a$ $b$ and $c$.

Am I supposed to differentiate the polynomial and then set $2=2ax+b$? Then differentiate again and set $0=2a$?

Answer (score 1):

From $f(x) = -x^3 + ax^2 + bx +c$, you have $f'(2) = 0 $ (maximum) and $f''(0)=0$ (inflection point). You also have $f(0) = -6$, $f(2) = 10$. That's enough equations.

$f'(x) = -3 x^2 + 2 ax + b$, $f''(x)= -6x+2a$.

When you do $f''(0)=0$, you get $a$. Then, when you do $f'(2)=0$ and plug in $a$, you get b. Then plugging in either of the points on the curve will give you $c$ (that is, $f(0) = -6$ or $f(2)=10$).